# django rest framework serializer return name not integer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a simple list view where the current return looks like this -

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "description": "John's Group",
        "owner": 1
    }
]
```

The problem is I don't want that integer I want it to show like this -

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "description": "John's Group",
        "owner": "John Smith"
    }
]
```

The only way around this I have found is to do a serializer like this -

```
class ClassListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ownername = serializers.CharField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model=ClassList
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'ownername')
```

The problem is that I don't want to have to change the field to `ownername`.

Setting the following in the model works for traditional querying of the model -

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

But I guess because DRF reads differently it doesn't adhere to the ForeignKey mapping and return?

Doing this doesn't work because it's trying to override `owner` with `owner` that already exists -

```
class ClassListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model=ClassList
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'owner')
```

So how do I get it to display the name instead of the integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) are exactly what you're looking for:

```
class ClassListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model=ClassList
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'owner')
```

Comment: I've learned in my years I have a problem with RTFM.  Thanks for this exactly what I wanted!